# How to set false to ASP Button if Ajax result is success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, winforms

I am calling Ajax when user click the button. When calling ajax it will **check the data with textbox whether the textbox value is already exist or not**. If exist, then it should not **return false**, if the record is not found in database, jquery button should **return true** let it to save on database through server side.

**Note:**

> My Ajax code is working. But when I the is exist and set `return false` this statement is not execute.

Here is my code:

```
$('#btnSaveFile').click(function () {
    var fileNames = $('#txtFileName').val();
    var flags = 'test';
    alert('test='+flags);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot',
        method: 'post',
        async:false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{fileName:"' + fileNames + '",reportName:"TotalSales"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d === 'dataExist') {

                 // it execute this loop, but after it execute it's going to server

                $('#lblSaveErrorMsg').text('This filename already exist. Please change the name');
                return false;

            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Please Call Administrator');                
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Make the request synchronous

Comment: @SankarRaj Can you give me more information.

Comment: set `async:false` in your ajax request.

Comment: @SankarRaj I did as you said. Still the same. Please check my code again. i will update my code now

Comment: not `async:'false'` just `async : false,`

Comment: @SankarRaj I tried, Still the same way it's executing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139485/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-sankar-raj).

Answer (score 0):

I found result myself.

Ajax is an Asynchronous. We cannot do `return false` when the result is `success`.

So I declare one variable outside of `ajax` and with the certain condition in success I set return false in outside of ajax code

**This is my Jquery code**

```
    $('#btnSaveFile').click(function () {
    var fileNames = $('#txtFileName').val();
    var flag = 'returnTrue';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot',
        method: 'post',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{fileName:"' + fileNames + '",reportName:"TotalSales"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d === 'dataExist') {
                flag = 'returnFalse';
                $('#lblSaveErrorMsg').text('This filename already exist. Please change the name');
            }
            else {
                alert('else');
                return true;
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Please Call Administrator');

        }
    });

    if (flag === 'returnFalse') {
        return false;
    }

});
```